# Java 8 stream with two Lists

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a method takes 2 lists as parameters and as you can see in the method body I want to do some filtering and returning the result to the caller. I wanted to convert this code to the Java 8 stream with lambda expressions but I couldn't figure that out. I ended up creating more than one stream for this and it beats the purpose of this refactoring (IMHO). What I wanted to know is that how I do, in a simple way, refactor this into just one stream?

```
public Set<CustomerTrack> getCustomerTracks(List<CusomerTrack> tracks, List<Customer> customers) {
    Set<CustomerTrack> tracksToSave = new HashSet<>();
    for (Customer customer : customers) {
        if (customer.getTrack() == null) {
            continue;
        }
        Long allowedTrackId = customer.getTrack().getId();
        for (CustomerTrack track : tracks) {
            if (Long.valueOf(track.getId()).equals(allowedTrackId)) {
                tracksToSave.add(track);
            }
        }
    }
    return tracksToSave;
}
```

Comment: I really suggest You put the tracks into the hashmap of id --> object, now You got O(n2) complexity, this is simply not efificient

Comment: @maslan do you have any source that I can read about the problem you refering to? I want to understand it well :)  (I think I understand the problem now). Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: the problem is simple, you have a `List` if ids in `customers`; for *each* of those ids you are traversing the `tracks` list to find what you need. traversing a list has `O(n)` complexity and since you do that for each element, your general complexity is `O(n * m)`. If you would first create a `Set` of ids from `customer` - you would improve the efficiency, since `contains` in a `Set` has the complexity of `O(1)`

Comment: @Eugene (`Set` -> `HashSet` in difference to e.g. `TreeSet` and O(log n)) - am I right?

Comment: so you would still need to traverse one Set (which is `O(n)`), but searching is now `O(1)` in the other one; thus making the total time to be `O(n) + O(1)`, since `O(1)` is constant, it can be removed, thus making your total solution `O(n)` - much better than what you had before.

Comment: @LuCio I wanted to edit that.. but 5 minutes have already passed. thank you for the heads up, still

Comment: @Eugene can you edit your answer to  reflect your comment above? In order to improve the efficiency?

Comment: @Yonetmen I think You got it from Your comment, but before traversing the tracks You could create a HashMap  map = tracks.stream.collect(Collectors.tomap(t -> t.getId(), Functions.identity())) and instead of the second loop for (CustomerTrack track : tracks) You can just do map.get(track.getId())

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seems that this is what you are after:

```
 customers.stream() 
          .filter(c -> c.getTrack() != null)
          .map(c -> c.getTrack().getId())
          .flatMap(id -> tracks.stream().filter(track -> Long.valueOf(track.getId()).equals(id)))
          .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Just note that for each `id` you are iterating the entire list of `tracks`; this has `O(n*m)` complexity. This is generally see as bad and you can improve it.

To make it better you would first create a `HashSet` of ids from `Customer`; having that `HashSet` you can now call `contains` on it with the ids you are interested in, since `contains` has a time complexity of `O(1)` (it's really called *amortized* complexity of `O(1)`). So now your complexity becomes `O(n)` + `O(1)`, but since `O(1)` is a constant, it's really `O(n)` - much better that what you had before. In code:

```
Set<Long> set = customers.stream()
            .filter(c -> c.getTrack() != null)
            .map(c -> c.getTrack().getId())
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());

Set<CusomerTrack> tracksToSave = tracks.stream()
            .filter(track -> set.contains(track.getId())
            .collect(Collectors.toSet()));
```

Comment: Hi Eugene, can you show me the most efficient way as well?

Comment: @Yonetmen just did... (I have not compiled this code, I honestly hope I did not miss anything, like a comma or a parenthesis)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you can create a Set of allowed Ids:

```
  Set<Long> collect = customers.stream()
                .filter(customer -> customer.getTrack() != null)
                .map(customer -> customer.getTrack().getId())
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Then you can filler your track collection

```
 Set<CusomerTrack> tracksToSave = tracks.stream()
                .filter(track -> collect.contains(Long.valueOf(track.getId())))
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but `collect.contains(track.getId()))` should be replaced with `collect.contains(Long.valueOf(track.getId())))`

Comment: @Yonetmen why should the simple and straight-forward `collect.contains(track.getId())` get replaced with `collect.contains(Long.valueOf(track.getId()))`?

Comment: @Holger In my case `CustomerTrack` Id field is a type of String.

Comment: @Yonetmen that would be a valuable information for the question. How is any answerer supposed to know this requirement? And why does the first `customer.getTrack().getId()` return a `Long` then?

Comment: @Holger Ok, its my bad! I shouldn't point it out because it was irrelevant. But I can explain it since you asked. `getTrack()` in `customer` object returns a `Track` entity and `CustomerTrack` is just used for messaging (deserialized object)

Answer (score 1):

An additional way favoring method reference usage :

```
Set<Track> tracks = 
customers.stream()
         .map(Customer::getTrack) // customer to track
         .filter(Objects::nonNull) // keep non null track
         .map(Track::getId)      // track to trackId
         .flatMap(trackId -> tracks.stream() // collect tracks matching with trackId
                                   .filter(t-> Long.valueOf(t.getId()).equals(trackId))
         )
         .collect(toSet());
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this

```
customers
    .stream()
    .map(Customer::getTrack)
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .map(CustomerTrack::getId)
    .flatMap(trackId -> tracks
                        .stream()
                        .filter(track -> Long.valueOf(track.getId()).equals(trackId)))
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: that will not compile, `flatMap` needs to return a `Stream`, you return a `Set`

Answer (score 0):

The important Operator here is `flatMap`

```
Set<CustomerTrack> tracksToSave = customers.stream()
   .map(Customer::getTrack)
   .filter(track -> track != null)
   .flatMap(track -> {
      tracks.stream.filter(it -> Long.valueOf(it.getId()).equals(track.getId())))
   .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Comment: dehasi's answer is probably better

Comment: I got confused with the Lambda syntax - thanks Eugene :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
customers.stream()
          .filter(customer -> customer.getTrack() != null)
          .map(c -> c.getTrack().getId())
          .forEach(allowedTrackId -> { 
           tracks.stream()
          .filter(track -> Long.valueOf(track.getId()).equals(allowedTrackId))
          .forEach(tracksToSave::add);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter the null values first and then filter it with the list of customerTrack.

Hope this answer helps you.

```
return customers.stream().map(cust-> cust.track).filter(track -> track != null).
            collect(Collectors.toList())
            .stream().filter(track-> customerTracks.stream()
                    .anyMatch(ele -> ele.getId() == 
track.getId())).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```